# Nested json query

Tags: sql, json, parsing, ssms

I am pretty new to this but I am taking over a process for someone and am struggling with json. Some Data examples below...

```
{"Label":"Appearance","ListId":"e5fbcbb3-1c02-4f9e-a6c6-0761755bb3b7"}

{"Label":"Are Gatekeepers using Tablets or Paper?","ListId":"80da3eb2-104f-433d-9939-9d2348585b4f"}

{"Label":"Defects","ListId":"0afcec98-fa5e-4f85-89dd-ec3f7b618b4d"}
```

what I need out of both of these is the ListId.

```
SELECT 
JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.Label') AS Label
,JSON_VALUE(x.value, '$.ListId') AS ListId
FROM test_db.stg.tabletest fci
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(fci.Content) AS X
WHERE fci.content LIKE '%ListId%' --this is needed because not every record has ListId..
```

I have verified that all records in question are JSON by using ISJSON.

I then ran the query above and expected to see data for both Label and ListId but I received the error also noted above.

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character 'D' is found at position 0

I ordered the records and they are all consistent in formatting so I am really confused as to what the issue is.